# Embedding of a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth, n-dimensional manifold. Prove that for every $k \leq n$ there exists an embedding $ \mathbb{R}^k \to M$.

I'm having trouble visualising this. How can $\mathbb{R}^2$ be embedded into the 2-dimensional torus, considering that the torus is a compact manifold and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is certainly not. $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is supposed to be a submanifold of the torus and there are not that many options left. Is there something obvious I'm forgetting?

Comment: Your unease with $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the torus is warranted.  If $f: X\to Y$ is an embedding and $Y$ is compact, then the properness of $f$ implies that $f^{-1}(Y)$, i.e. $X$ itself, is compact. So the statement cannot be true in general (if you assume embeddings are proper). Where did you find the statement/problem?

Comment: Embeddings are proper iff they are closed, which need not be the case in general.

Comment: A manifold has embedded charts by definition, and into these we may embed Euclidean spaces of smaller dimension.

Answer (score 2):

An open disc on any surface is always diffeomorphic to the whole $\Bbb{R}^2$. To see that, take for example the smooth, invertible map (in polar coordinates): 
$$
\theta \mapsto \theta\\
r\mapsto \arctan r.
$$

Comment: But I need a diffeomorphism onto its image, don't I?

Comment: Sure, sorry, edited.

Comment: So then I can take $\Bbb{R}^k$ and it's diffeomorphic to an open disc on the manifold and that finishes the proof?

Comment: Yeah, I think so.